# ERR_TIMED_OUT for HTTPS request only on Chrome and Mozilla

Tags: google-chrome, cross-browser

We build a website in asp.net and it was working fine. Last 2-3 days I noticed it took lots of time (more than 30 sec) to load the page only on Chrome and Mozilla. Other browsers (Safari, Internet Explorer etc) are working fine.

I'm using Chrome latest version 74.0.3729.131 (Official Build) (64-bit). In the developer's console, it shows the following error message for each request

[image]

Then I noticed those requests are timeout because of HTTPS. I request the page with HTTP then it's loading fine. But my website is HTTPS so I should request all with HTTPS unless it don't load the page.
example - https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.5.1/1/WebForms.js

[image]

I also tried the following ways but it couldn't work,

1. Uninstall and reinstall Chrome.
2. Delete all cookies and sessions.
3. Restarted wifi router (IP changed).
4. Restarted firewall.

But it works on some of the client machines and when I use chrome proxy extension and visit the website from a different country. I feel the issue is from the network or IP address. I don't know how to fix it. Please help me to fix...

Comment: Have you found a solution to this yet?

Comment: @Bmize729 I didn't find the solution. But after few days later it started to work fine.